# Custom fields: my custom checkbox area doesn't seem to work

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to create my own custom fields meta box filled with just checkboxes in pages. I'm basing it off [this tutorial here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes/). I was able to get the original tutorial to work, but when I started to simplify it down just to saving a checkbox, it stopped working: the checkbox won't save the 'on' state when I update the page.

I'm sure this has something to do with the saving portion of the function. Anyone have any clues, tips, or hints? Thanks!

```
<?php function cd_meta_box_cb() { 
// Some settings first:
    global $post;
    $check = isset( $values['page_title_off'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['page_title_off'][0] ) : '';    
    // We'll use this nonce field later on when saving.
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
// Render the custom fields:
?>  
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="page_title_off" name="page_title_off" <?php checked( $check, 'on' ); ?> />
        <label for="page_title_off">Turn off page title</label>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;
    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;
    // now we can actually save the data
    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() // and those anchors can only have href attribute
        )
    );
    // Save
    if( isset( $_POST['page_title_off'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'page_title_off', $_POST['page_title_off'] );

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through all this yesterday!

According to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) there must be a post id given to current_user_can to check 'edit_post', so your capability check should be:

```
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;
```

Also, your final two lines should be more like this:

```
$chk = isset( $_REQUEST['page_title_off'] ) ? 'on' : 'off';  
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'page_title_off', $chk );
```

This should turn the post meta on or off depending on whether the checkbox was ticked.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! However, it's still not saving the check every update click. Do I have this right? http://jsfiddle.net/foomarks/mH2QT/

Comment: Change your $_POST to $_REQUEST: '$chk = isset( $_REQUEST['page_title_off'] ) ? 'on' : 'off';'

Comment: Thanks for that clue! But argh, still not working. I feel like I'm so close! I updated the code to your suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/foomarks/mH2QT/1/

Comment: I would suggest adding some debug code to see if the save function is actually being called, and if so, what the values of all the variables are.